# Derivative of the Exponential map explained

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to understand how to interpret the derivative of the exponential map in terms of the Jacobi field?  Define the map
$$
f(x):Exp_p(x),
$$
where the Riemannian manifold is on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with a non-Euclidean Riemannian metric making it geodesically complete.
Is there a nice expression for it's gradient?

Comment: I do not even know how to start looking for it.